# Format unix timestamp to something readable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, google-analytics, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to parse some bits through the google analytics cookie parser, I have this:

```
:Time_of_first_visit__c => Time.new(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:initial_visit_at)).to_datetime.to_formatted_s(:long),
:Time_of_previous_visit__c => Time.new(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:previous_visit_at)).to_datetime.to_formatted_s(:long),
:Current_visit_time__c => Time.new(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:current_visit_at)).to_datetime.to_formatted_s(:long),
```

But it's rendered like this:

Time of first visit
January 01, 1375174064 00:00

Current visit time
January 01, 1375174064 00:00

Time of previous visit 
January 01, 1375174064 00:00

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the code I went with in the end:

```
:Time_of_first_visit__c => Time.at(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:initial_visit_at).to_i + 1.hour).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p"),
:Time_of_previous_visit__c => Time.at(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:previous_visit_at).to_i + 1.hour).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p"),
:Current_visit_time__c => Time.at(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:current_visit_at).to_i + 1.hour).strftime("%B %e, %Y at %I:%M %p"),
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove `to_formatted_s(:long)` and use it as argument of `I18n.l`

example:

```
I18n.l Time.new(@data.utma_hash.fetch(:initial_visit_at)).to_datetime
```

Of course you need a specification of datetime formats in your language .yml file, but it should work with the default one you can find in the official guides